# For a point-and-shoot travel camera, what features matter the most?

Tags: equipment-recommendation, travel, gps, photography-basics

For a GPS-enabled point-and-shoot camera mainly to be used when traveling and hiking, what specific features or criteria can be used to narrow the field of possible cameras?

Ideally this camera would also be good for capturing everyday outings.

---

*Original Question:*

I'm a noob photographer who needs the camera mainly for snapshots. Particularly there are three opportunities when I take pictures, ordered by priority:

1. Taking pictures while traveling. There I want to make pictures of sights, but also landscape or persons
2. Taking pictures when hiking, both in the summer and during winter.
3. Taking pictures when going out and having fun

So as you can see these are three very different kind of pictures. Additionally, I have some further requirements. It is absolutely necessary that the camera supports automatic geo-tagging with GPS and it should not be too heavy since I'm carrying it even when doing sports.

Based on these features (not too big, geo-tagging), I have selected all possible cameras on [www.digitec.ch](http://www.digitec.ch). The problem now is that there are almost 100 possible candidates. So what additional criteria can I use to choose a camera?

Comment: Asking what camera to buy it's just too vague, no one has ever used a great number of cameras (100) to provide real good info about a group of them. When a user comes up with a brand for their first time and he is satisfied with why buy any other? If not, they might come up with buying a world famous one, Nikon or Canon, I guess. After all cameras are expensive devices, nevertheless if you want something light and agile, maybe a mirrorless camera will be the best solution here, so if you have some in your list check them out. They tend to be smaller than DSLR's but with the same performance.

Comment: But he _is_ asking for selection criteria, not "what camera". I wish more equipment recommendation were asking about generic guidelines rather than specific models.

Comment: Exactly. I know shopping recommendation questions are usually not allowed on SE, that's why I want to get more information how I can assess the quality of these cameras by myself.

Comment: Got it, my bad. As features I would recommend for you to add Image stabilization, for point 2 and 3 it looks like it would be very useful.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a camera that's going to be used during hiking and sporting, drop and weather resistance might be beneficial. You can find those cameras by selecting the "Waterproof" options.

"Going out and having fun" suggests looking for good light gathering ability for better quality of low-light shots and faster shutter speeds in action shots. This is usually achieved through larger sensor size and lenses with smaller f-number. Unfortunately there are no search options on Digitec for such info; you might have to skim some reviews and look for "low light performance", "high ISO handling" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks for the good tips. So I used them do narrow down my choice to this one. What do you think about it? http://digitec.ch/ProdukteDetails2.aspx?Reiter=Bilder&Artikel=207072